# Typescript: "X" is not assignable to type, types of property "Y" are incompatible

Tags: angular, date, typescript

Note: I am quite new to Angular2 and typescript, so I am sorry for my ignorance.

The issue:
What I'm trying to do is to subtract a start date/time from the end date/time then use that in a formula for my calculation to display as "calc". The problem is that I can give calc a static number which works, but if I try to use the math formula it gives all kinds of errors when transpiling:

> 1
>   mock-orders.ts(4,14): error TS2322: Type '{ order_no: string; scheduled: string; lateral: string; start_time: string; checks: string; stop_...' is not assignable to type 'Order[]'.
>
> Type '{ order_no: string; scheduled: string; lateral: string; start_time: string; checks: string; stop_...' is not assignable to type 'Order'.
>
> Types of property 'checks' are incompatible.
>
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Below is the child component where I'm having these issues. 
See line 28 this.calc:

```
     // order.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class Order {
    order_no: string;
    scheduled: string;
    lateral: string;
    start_time: string;
    checks: number;
    stop_time: string;
    status: string;
    approx_cfs: string;
    approx_hrs: string;
    approx_af: string;
    calc: number;

    constructor(data: {} = {}) {
    this.order_no = data["order_no"] || "";
    this.scheduled = data["scheduled"] || "";
    this.lateral = data["lateral"] || "";
    this.start_time = data["start_time"] || "";
    this.checks = data["checks"] || "";
    this.stop_time = data["stop_time"] || "";
    this.status = data["status"] || "";
    this.approx_cfs = data["approx_cfs"] || "";
    this.approx_hrs = data["approx_hrs"] || "";
    this.approx_af = data["approx_af"] || "";
    this.calc = (!this.stop_time ? ((new Date().getTime() - new Date(this.start_time).getTime()) / 1000.0 / 60.0 / 60.0) * this.checks * 0.0825 : ((new Date(this.stop_time).getTime() - new Date(this.start_time).getTime()) /1000.0 / 60.0 / 60.0) * this.checks * 0.0825); 

    console.log(this.calc);
    };

};
```

Part of the issue, I'm sure, is that I'm trying to use math operations on dates, then assign the result to a number type.

The following call this component for use in the service:

```
// order.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Order } from './order';
import { ORDERS } from './mock-orders';

@Injectable()
export class OrderService {
  getOrders(): Promise<Order[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(ORDERS);
  }
}
```

The following file is the data arrays pulled each time the service runs, to depict what will be received from the database.

```
// mock-orders.ts
import { Order } from './order'

export const ORDERS: Order[] = [ 
    {order_no: '12345',
    scheduled: '08/16/16 13:45',
    lateral: 'L1-8-1-T7, L1-8-1-T6',
    start_time: '08/16/16 15:45',
    checks: '23.25',
    stop_time: '08/17/16 15:30', 
    status: 'Delivered',
    approx_cfs: '25.00',
    approx_hrs: '22',
    approx_af: '45.38',
    },

    {order_no: '12346',
    scheduled: '08/17/16 11:45',
    lateral: 'L1-8-1-T7, L1-8-1-T6',
    start_time: '08/17/16 15:30',
    checks: '20.25',
    stop_time: '', 
    status: 'Running',
    approx_cfs: '25.00',
    approx_hrs: '10',
    approx_af: '20.63',
    },

    {order_no: '12346',
    scheduled: '08/17/16 11:45',
    lateral: 'L1-8-1-T7, L1-8-1-T6',
    start_time: '08/17/16 15:30',
    checks: '20.25',
    stop_time: '', 
    status: 'Running',
    approx_cfs: '25.00',
    approx_hrs: '10',
    approx_af: '20.63',
    },

    {order_no: '12346',
    scheduled: '08/17/16 11:45',
    lateral: 'L1-8-1-T7, L1-8-1-T6',
    start_time: '08/17/16 15:30',
    checks: '20.25',
    stop_time: '', 
    status: 'Running',
    approx_cfs: '25.00',
    approx_hrs: '10',
    approx_af: '20.63',
    }
];
```

Comment: `this.checks` is declared as a string, and you are trying to perform some math on that with other data types. That may be where the issues is. Try declaring it as a number.

Comment: Updated with number typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since `Date.parse()` first tries to cast the input into number and then get the equivalent date out of it, and in js casting strings with characters other than number like '-' or '/' will cause in NaN result the Date.parse will also return NaN. You can use `new Date(str: String)` in this case to make a date object from a valid date string. you can also use `getTime()` function for mathematical operations on dates.

```js
let data = {
  order_no: '12346',
  scheduled: '08/17/16 11:45',
  lateral: 'L1-8-1-T7, L1-8-1-T6',
  start_time: '08/17/16 15:30',
  checks: '20.25',
  stop_time: '', 
  status: 'Running',
  approx_cfs: '25.00',
  approx_hrs: '10',
  approx_af: '20.63',
 };
this.order_no = data["order_no"] || "";
this.scheduled = data["scheduled"] || "";
this.lateral = data["lateral"] || "";
this.start_time = data["start_time"] || "";
this.checks = data["checks"] || "";
this.stop_time = data["stop_time"] || "";
this.status = data["status"] || "";
this.approx_cfs = data["approx_cfs"] || "";
this.approx_hrs = data["approx_hrs"] || "";
this.approx_af = data["approx_af"] || "";
this.calc = (!this.stop_time ? ((new Date().getTime() - new Date(this.start_time).getTime()) / 1000.0 / 60.0 / 60.0) * this.checks * 0.0825 : ((new Date(this.stop_time).getTime() - new Date(this.start_time).getTime()) /1000.0 / 60.0 / 60.0) * this.checks * 0.0825); 

console.log(calc);
```

Comment: This is progress. I now get error-->Type '{ order_no: string; scheduled: string; lateral: string; start_time: string; checks: string; stop_...' is not assignable to type 'Order[]'.
  Type '{ order_no: string; scheduled: string; lateral: string; start_time: string; checks: string; stop_...' is not assignable to type 'Order'.
    Types of property 'checks' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are trying to assign string type value to checks variable which is of type number.

`start_time: string;
 checks: number;
 stop_time: string;`

Assigned values:-

`start_time: '08/17/16 15:30',
 checks: '20.25',
 stop_time: '',`

Comment: If I change it to string the formula no longer will function. How do I keep a floating point in that formula?

Comment: While assigning values specify without quotes.

Comment: Something like checks: 26.25